# How to add commans to a select of an decimal (18,2)?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm basically trying to format the sql correctly to appear as money.  This is what I have but i cannot get the commas to appear!

`SELECT   '$'
       + CONVERT (
            NVARCHAR (30),
            CONVERT (NUMERIC (30, 2),
                     round (CONVERT (MONEY, 321321321.321231), 2)))
          AS 'Accrued'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(varchar(max), CAST(321321321.321231 AS money), 1)
```